Не работает функция подсчета вхождений в массив array в библиотеке NumPy в Пайтоне
Использую Python -интерпретатор Spyder 3.11. Все бы хорошо, но не работает функция count для подсчета числа вхождений в массив. Перепроверял возможности использования функций для класса array. Функция должна вызываться через точку после названия массива - все верно. Пробовал менять название массива и использовать одномерный массив вместо двумерного - но функция count вызывает ту же ошибку: "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'count'". .
Подскажите, что делаю не так?


Вы же давно на SO. И не научились код показывать текстом, а не картинкой??? И почему вы решили, что count должно работать для массива?

Я задавал мало вопросов :)
Кто подскажет, как задать код текстом? Простая вставка выглядит баналньно:
import numpy as np;
array1 = np.array([[1,2],[5,5]]);
#a = array1.count(2);
print(np.count_nonzero(array1 == 5));

Выделить код и нажать кнопку {} над окном редактора




Spyder - это не интерпретатор. 2) - где вы вообще нашли метод count для массива numpy, что ж вы там такого читали? 3) - код скриншотом -- это позор.




А вообще там ещё вагон вариантов, как это можно сделать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663856/how-do-i-count-the-occurrence-of-a-certain-item-in-an-ndarray

Не все источники информации достоверны: Я обжегся на
https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-array-massivy-v-python.html
array.count(х) - возвращает количество вхождений х в массив. :))

Здесь рабочий вариант https://www.codecamp.ru/blog/numpy-count/

numpy.count_nonzero:
print(np.count_nonzero(array1 == 2))


import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[2,7],[2,2]])
len(a[a==2])


4

